# Android - remove whatever contains the file

Tags: android, file

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
File myFile = cw.getDir("mydata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Now please tell me how to remove whatever contains(mainly images) myFile(folder), how to clear it?

Comment: Check here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994518/how-to-delete-the-content-of-text-file-without-deleting-itself

Comment: What do you mean by 'Clear'? Do you mean Deleting files itself or just deleting data from it?

Answer (score 1):

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("fileName.txt");
pw.close();
```

**OR**

```
new RandomAccessFile(fileName).setLength(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to clear a folder is by recursion:

```
void deleteDirContent(File file) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        for (File child : file.listFiles())
            deleteDirContent(child); <--------
    }
    file.delete();
}
```