# How to empty file content without deleting the file in java?

Tags: java, file, io

```
FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter("C:/Users/NULL NULL NULL/Desktop/New Text Document.txt", false); // set the write to false so we dont append to it

BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(fwriter); // this is the type so we can write to it.

write.write(""); // write empty string to delet everything

write.close(); // close the buffer to gain back memory space that the buffer
```

took up.

Comment: First what is the question ? Second have you tested the code you have pointed ?

Comment: I believe this is duplicate of this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994518/how-to-delete-the-content-of-text-file-without-deleting-itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994518/how-to-delete-the-content-of-text-file-without-deleting-itself)

Answer (score 6):

How about this:

```
File file = new File("myfile");
if(file.exists()){
    file.delete();
}
file.createNewFile();
```

Or this, which will create a new file OR overwrite existing one:

```
Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("myfile"));
```

Or @CandiedOrange's PrinterWriter:

```
new PrintWriter("myfile").close();
```

Otherwise, the good old way:

```
File file = new File("myfile");
FileOutputStream fooStream = new FileOutputStream(file, false);

fooStream.write("".getBytes());
fooStream.close();
```

Comment: What's wrong with just `new PrintWriter("filepath.txt").close();`?

Comment: Nothing wrong, just millions of ways to do it :)  I've added your suggestion into the mix